# create a range from arguments

Tags: python, range, command-line-arguments

Really new to python but I'm trying to practice and do things using python to make the learning experience interesting, I am trying to do a a scanner for a range of ports, but I want to specify the ports as a cli argument. However, when I put them on the range, nothing happens so I think I'm not parsing the arguments properly, how do I do this?

Here is part of my code:

```
host = sys.argv[1]
first_port = sys.argv[2]
ending_port = sys.argv[3]


print "Checking ports on the range of " + start_port + " to " + end_port

try:
    for port in range(first_port, ending_port):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = s.connect_ex((host, port))
        if result == 0:
            print "--> Port " + str(port) + "open"
        s.close()
except:
    pass
```

If I put `range(1, 1024)` it does work but is not liking the way I pass my arguments. Also, I tried converting to int with `first_port = int(sys.argv[2])` for example, but again nothing happens. What am I missing on this?

Comment: You need to convert both inputs to range.

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
first_port = sys.argv[2]
ending_port = sys.argv[3]


print "Checking ports on the range of " + start_port + " to " + end_port
```

to

```
first_port = int(sys.argv[2])
ending_port = int(sys.argv[3])


print "Checking ports on the range of {} to {}".format(first_port, ending_port)
```

yields the correct behavior.   Also, you probably want to range on

```
for port in range(first_port, ending_port+1):
```

since the end of range is non-inclusive.

The big lesson here (in my opinion) is don't use `pass` in an `except` unless you explicitly know it should be passed.  If you had some error with your input params then you would just be swallowing the exception instead of getting a helpful stacktrace / error message.

Comment: ah thanks about the non-inclusive issue, you are right. In regards to the original issue, I did try that, I put it ont he comments, the `first_port = int(sys.argv[2])` does not do anything, the program simply does nothing when it runs.

Comment: Well, unless you also removed the `pass` in except and replaced it with something useful (start with `raise`) then you can't be sure you did the same thing.